# UIPanGestureRecognizer global translate coordinate

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to drag an image out of `UICollectionViewCell` and then see if it collides with another image somewhere else on the screen. 
To do I need to be able to match their translation coordinate. It is my understanding that since the image is within the collectionView cell it is tracked relative cell coordinate and I need to to be tracker globally.

```
|---------------------------------------|
|        _______                        |
|       |_image_|                       |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
|       |image|     Collection View     |
|---------------------------------------|
```

So far when I'm dragging the image over another one I'm getting this as a log:

```
moved imageView center: (-44.0, -143.5)
destination imageView center: (440.0, 175.0)

let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self.view.superview)
self.view.center = CGPoint(x: self.initialLocation.x + translation.x, y: self.initialLocation.y + translation.y)
```

I also tried replacing `self.view.superview` with `mainView` but to no avail:

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainView = window.rootViewController?.view
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I track the dragged image on the global scale?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you have to follow procedure.

1. First of all, when `panGesture` called you have to create a [snapshot](https://gist.github.com/peatiscoding/83852abe8150e66da1b3b4855e8f7b84) of that `view/imageview` (what so ever).
2. Add that snapsnot as a subview of `self.view` (VC main view)
3. To get positon of your view w.r.t main view you have to use [convert(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert). Now set frame of snapshot according to this.
4. You can hide your `view/imageview` after this so that in user interaction it looked like user moving that same `view/Imgview`.
5. Now match your image and do what so ever you wanted to do.
6. If you wanted to put that image at its original space then unhide that image when user ended from the `panGesture`.

hope now you will be more cleared what you have to do actually.